# Problem with rendering address field on profile page

Tags: magento2, template, render

I have a problem like in attachment. I don't know why address isn't rendering. Please help me how to debug this.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen when you switch back to the native `default/default` Magento template ?

Comment: This is Magento blank theme template. It happend right after instalation.

Comment: Which Magento version ? No extension installed ?

Comment: Magento 2.0.2 CE. No extensions. Clean installation. This is test enviroment CentOS (nginx, php5.6.9). What is interesting, I have installed Magento on local enviroment and everything works Ubuntu (nginx, php5.6.18). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by inability to load address attributes from EAV tables in the database. Magento assumes values of certain IDs invariant and thus they're hard-coded in a PHP code for performance optimization purposes. Attribute set ID = 2 is hard-coded for address attributes. However, the field `eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and thus is governed by MySQL settings [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) and [auto_increment_offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset). Having non-default values for those settings is the root cause of the issue.

**The fix:**

1. Make changes to the MySQL config `my.cnf`:

   - `auto_increment_increment = 1`
   - `auto_increment_offset = 1`
2. Restart MySQL to apply the config changes
3. Create a new empty database
4. Re-install Magento from scratch to the new database

**Note:** Changing MySQL settings above will not recover the existing database.

Comment: You might have right. This server is working on Percona cluster. Rows multiply every 3 (for example 1,4,7). Thanks for the clarification. You're great.